# cannot load such file -- gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal, bundle

I got this error when I do bundle instal

bundle install
    /Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/nour/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/exe/bundle (LoadError)
        from /Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/bundle:23:in`'
        from /Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        from /Users/nour/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in`'

```
rails g controller home
Your Gemfile lists the gem byebug (>= 0) more than once.
You should probably keep only one of them.
Remove any duplicate entries and specify the gem only once.
While it's not a problem now, it could cause errors if you change the version of one of them later.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.11.1) was resolved to 4.2.11.1, which depends on
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.1.4)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 4.2.11.1)', in any of the sources.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Bundler 2.1.4, and Rails 4.2 does not work with Bundler 2 and above.

You need to install a supported bundler version like this:

```
gem install bundler:1.17.3
```

To use the newly installed version run:

```
bundle _1.17.3_ install
```

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Run: `bundle _1.17.3_ install`